# Start new table row every 3 cells

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am using ACF to fetch yacht listings (custom post types) which are then output in a table.

I could try and lay these out as Divs but this particular design means it is much easier as a table (there are borders in between and fluctuating heights which I would like to display of equal height).

The problem is, as these are populated dynamically, I am unable to lay the table out in html and thus, can't find a way to only have 3 cells wide per table row.

Is there a way to have a new row automatically start every 3 cells? Furthermore, is there a way to alter this based on screen width.

Currently the posts are not set in a table in the HTML but in the CSS, but I have tried both.

My code is:

```
    <div class="the-latest-listings">
    <div class="listings-table-row">
        <?php 
        
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'yachts',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'orderby' => 'date',
             'order' => 'DESC',

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'sale_or_charter',
                    'value' => 'sale',
                )
            ),
        );
    
        $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    
        if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) {
    
            while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post();
            
            ?>
            <div class='latest-yacht-wrapper'>
                
                    <div class="single-latest-yacht-container">             
                        
                        <div class="latest-yacht-image">
                             
                            <?php 
                                $image = get_field( "preview_yacht_image", get_the_ID() );?>
                                
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($image['title']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
            
                                </a>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    
                        
                    
                        <div class="latest-yacht-blue-container">       
                            
                            <div class="sale-status-tab">
                                <p><?php echo the_field( "sale_or_charter", get_the_ID() );?></p>
                            </div>  
                            
                                    
                            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            
                                <div class="teaser-details">    
                                
                                        <?php if( get_field('price', get_the_ID() ) ){ ?>
                                            <p class="latest-price">EUR <?php echo get_field( "price", get_the_ID() );?></p>
                                            <p class="divider">|</p>
                                        <?php }; ?> 
                                        
                        
                                        
                                
                                </div>      
                                
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="yacht-spacer">
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
            </div>  
            
            <?php
    
            endwhile;
    
            wp_reset_postdata();
    
        }
        
        ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And the CSS that is think is relevant to the question

```
#page .the-latest-listings {
    border-top: 1.3px solid rgba(28,34,64,.3);
    border-bottom: 1.3px solid rgba(28,34,64,.3);
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

 .listings-table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.latest-yacht-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
}

.single-latest-yacht-container {
    padding: 78px 0;
}


.yacht-spacer {
    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}
```

I tried setting the .latest-yacht-wrapper to 33% width but it doesn't work. I also tried these:

```
    while($('.the-latest-listings ').find('tr:last').children(':gt(2)').length > 0){
   $('.the-latest-listings ').find('tr:last').after(
       $('.the-latest-listings ').find('tr:last').children(':gt(2)')
           .wrapAll('<tr></tr>').parent().remove()
   );
}
```

AND

```
while($('.the-latest-listings').find('tr:last').children(':gt(2)').length > 0){
           var newRow = '';
           $('.the-latest-listings').find('tr:last').children(':gt(2)').each(function(i,e){
              newRow += $(e).prop('outerHTML');
           }).remove();
           $('.the-latest-listings').find('tr:last').after('<tr>' + newRow + '</tr>');
        }
```

I also tried switching to a table layout in the html like so:

```
<table class="the-latest-listings">
    <tr class="listings-table-row">
        <?php 
        
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'yachts',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'orderby' => 'date',
             'order' => 'DESC',

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'sale_or_charter',
                    'value' => 'sale',
                )
            ),
        );
    
        $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    
        if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) {
    
            while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post();
            
            ?>
            <td class='latest-yacht-wrapper'>
                
                    <div class="single-latest-yacht-container">             
                        
                        <div class="latest-yacht-image">
                             
                            <?php 
                                $image = get_field( "preview_yacht_image", get_the_ID() );?>
                                
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($image['title']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
            
                                </a>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    
                        
                    
                        <div class="latest-yacht-blue-container">       
                            
                            <div class="sale-status-tab">
                                <p><?php echo the_field( "sale_or_charter", get_the_ID() );?></p>
                            </div>  
                            
                                    
                            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            
                                <div class="teaser-details">    
                                
                                        <?php if( get_field('price', get_the_ID() ) ){ ?>
                                            <p class="latest-price">EUR <?php echo get_field( "price", get_the_ID() );?></p>
                                            <p class="divider">|</p>
                                        <?php }; ?> 
                                        
                        
                                        
                                
                                </div>      
                                
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
            </td>
            
            <td class="yacht-spacer">
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
            </td>   
            
            <?php
    
            endwhile;
    
            wp_reset_postdata();
    
        }
        
        ?>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

And then this:

```
var $td = $(".listings-table-row td");

$td.each(function(i){
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        $td.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<tr/>')
    }
}).parent('tr').unwrap();

But again, no luck.
```

As I am writing this, I realise accounting for the spacers will mean it's not 3 TD's across but I can't get any to work regardless of what numbers I enter.

Answer (score -1):

One of the following techniques could fit the bill:

- https://youtu.be/qm0IfG1GyZU?t=711
- https://youtu.be/qm0IfG1GyZU?t=184

### RAM (Repeat, Auto, Minmax)

```css
.ex7 .parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent white">
  <div class="box pink">1</div>
  <div class="box purple">2</div>
  <div class="box blue">3</div>
  <div class="box green">4</div>
</div>
```

### The Deconstructed Pancake

```css
.ex2 .parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ex2 .box {
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  /*  Stretching: */
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  /*  No stretching: */
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent white">
  <div class="box green">1</div>
  <div class="box green">2</div>
  <div class="box green">3</div>
</div>
```

(source https://1linelayouts.glitch.me/)